# copy data using formula in excel

Tags: excel

Please help, I have this situation. I am not sure how to solve with vlookup, if anyone can guide me that would be great help.

```
County  Status  Status Count
dublin  In      2   
dublin  out     1
dublin  closed  10
donegal closed  2
donegal in      5
```

Sheet 2 with

```
County  Economy     EconomyCount
dublin  good growth  23
dublin  average      15
donegal not good     14
```

I want result as

```
County  Status  Status Count    Economy     EconomyCount
dublin  In      2               good growth  23
dublin  out     1               average      15
dublin  closed  10              N/A       
donegal closed  2               not good     14
donegal in      5               N/A
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering your `Sheet1` is as

[image]

and `Sheet2` is

[image]

Assuming you are matching for the first occurrence, then in `Cell D2` of `Sheet1` enter the formula

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,$A2)=1,INDEX(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$3,MATCH($A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$3,0)),"N/A")
```

and in `Cell E2` of `Sheet1` enter the following formula

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,$A2)=1,INDEX(Sheet2!$C$2:$C$3,MATCH($A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$3,0)),"")
```

Drag/Copy down as required. See image for reference.

[image]

Comment: Thanks much for the help.

Comment: Is it possible to change your formula if sheet 2 have one more County Entry. Currently the check is at countif, Is there anyway to generalise this ?

Comment: If there's more county in `Sheet2` then you'll have to change the range in formula accordingly. For one more county in `Sheet2` i.e. if there are three counties then in formula `Sheet2!$A$2:$A$3` becomes `Sheet2!$A$2:$A$4`, `Sheet2!$B$2:$B$3` becomes `Sheet2!$B$2:$B$4` and `Sheet2!$C$2:$C$3` becomes `Sheet2!$C$2:$C$4`.

Comment: @SajithSudhi - So with this data in `Sheet2` what should be the result?

Comment: Let me rephrase the question.

Comment: @SajithSudhi - If the logic of question is going to change completely then I suggest you to ask a new question instead of editing this one.

Comment: @SajithSudhi - More people will be able to see your question, though you can give reference to this question.

Comment: This is posted now. here is the link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44918935/excel-column-need-to-be-matched-in-two-different-sheets

Comment: Kindly delete your newly posted question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44918935/excel-column-need-to-be-matched-in-two-different-sheets?noredirect=1#comment76815349_44918935).

Comment: Give some details on what is your criteria for assigning `Economy` to `Status` so that I can update my answer accordingly.