# Excel Column need to be matched in two different sheets

Tags: excel

### Yes there was a similar question. Previously Ming helped with the question. but I have a different scenario in the example. Please check and give me guidance.

Please help, I have this situation. I am not sure how to solve with vlookup, if anyone can guide me that would be a great help.

```
County  Status  Status Count
dublin  In      2   
dublin  out     1
dublin  closed  10
donegal closed  2
donegal in      5
```

Sheet 2 with

```
County  Economy     EconomyCount
dublin  good growth  23
dublin  average      15
donegal not good     14
```

I want result as Sheet 1 with

```
County  Status  Status Count    Economy     EconomyCount
dublin  In      2               good growth  23
dublin  out     1               average      15
dublin  closed  10              N/A       
donegal closed  2               not good     14
donegal in      5               N/A
```

This question has been extended from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44901787/copy-data-using-formula-in-excel) question.

Comment: What is your criteria for assigning `Economy` to `Status`?

Comment: @pnuts - I've edited [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44901787/copy-data-using-formula-in-excel) question to what was it previously asked. Now that question has changed after answer was accepted.

Comment: @pnuts - So I asked OP to post another question.

Comment: @pnuts - I guess this does not make the question duplicate.

Comment: @pnuts - So shall OP be asked to delete this question and upaccept my answer there?